# How can one use R within Google Cloud Datalab notebook

Tags: r, google-cloud-datalab

Is it possible (advisable) to use R within Google Cloud Datalab?  How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a pull request on Google Datalab. It is just a modification of the original docker file in the folder:

datalab/containers/base/**Dockerfile**

You can find the modified file here:
[My Git repository](https://github.com/renedlog/datalab/blob/master/containers/base/Dockerfile)

Or the full code inside the Dockerfile here (below). You need to push the Docker container to the container registry of google.
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# We use different base images for GPU vs CPU Dockerfiles, so we expect
# that the appropriate image is pulled and tagged locally.
# CPU should use ubuntu:16.04
# and GPU uses nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel-ubuntu16.04
FROM datalab-external-base-image
MAINTAINER Google Cloud DataLab

# Container configuration
EXPOSE 8080

# Path configuration
ENV PATH $PATH:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin
ENV PYTHONPATH /env/python

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

# Setup OS and core packages
RUN echo "deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y -q debian-archive-keyring debian-keyring && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q python unzip ca-certificates build-essential \
    libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev gfortran libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev libxml2-dev \
    libsnappy-dev python-dev python-setuptools python-zmq openssh-client wget curl git \
    pkg-config zip && \
    easy_install pip && \
    mkdir -p /tools && \

# Save GPL source packages
    mkdir -p /srcs && \
    cd /srcs && \
    apt-get source -d wget git python-zmq ca-certificates pkg-config libpng-dev && \
    wget --progress=dot:mega https://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2.tar.bz2 && \
    cd / && \

# Setup Python packages. Rebuilding numpy/scipy is expensive so we move this early
# to reduce the chance that prior steps can cause changes requiring a rebuild.
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir numpy==1.11.2 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pandas==0.19.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scipy==0.18.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scikit-learn==0.18.2 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scikit-image==0.13.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir lime==0.1.1.23 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir sympy==0.7.6.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir statsmodels==0.6.1 && \

    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir tornado==4.4.2 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pyzmq==16.0.2 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir jinja2==2.8 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir jsonschema==2.5.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir python-dateutil==2.5.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pytz==2016.7 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pandocfilters==1.3.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pygments==2.1.3 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir argparse==1.2.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir mock==2.0.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir requests==2.9.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir oauth2client==2.2.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir httplib2==0.10.3 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir futures==3.0.5 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir matplotlib==1.5.3 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ggplot==0.6.8 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir seaborn==0.7.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir PyYAML==3.11 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir six==1.10.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ipywidgets==6.0.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ipykernel==4.5.2 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir future==0.15.2 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir psutil==4.3.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir google-api-python-client==1.5.1  && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir plotly==1.12.5 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir nltk==3.2.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir bs4==0.0.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir crcmod==1.7 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pillow==3.4.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir google-cloud-dataflow==2.0.0 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir tensorflow==1.2.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir python-snappy==0.5.1 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir xgboost==0.6a2 && \
    find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -type d -name tests | xargs rm -rf && \

# Python 3
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q python3-dev && \
# Get pip set up such that pip -> py2 and pip3 -> py3
# And they both work.
    wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3 ./get-pip.py && \
    python ./get-pip.py --force-reinstall && \
    rm ./get-pip.py && \

# Install other Python 3 packages
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir numpy==1.11.2 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pandas==0.19.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scipy==0.18.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scikit-learn==0.18.2 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir scikit-image==0.13.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir lime==0.1.1.23 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir sympy==0.7.6.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir statsmodels==0.6.1 && \

    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir tornado==4.4.2 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pyzmq==16.0.2 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir jinja2==2.8 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir jsonschema==2.5.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir python-dateutil==2.5.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pytz==2016.7 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pandocfilters==1.3.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pygments==2.1.3 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir argparse==1.2.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir mock==2.0.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir requests==2.9.1 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir oauth2client==2.2.0 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir httplib2==0.10.3 \
                   --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir futures==3.0.5 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir matplotlib==1.5.3 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ggplot==0.6.8 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir seaborn==0.7.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir PyYAML==3.11 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir six==1.10.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir psutil==4.3.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir google-api-python-client==1.5.1  && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir plotly==1.12.5 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir nltk==3.2.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir bs4==0.0.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir crcmod==1.7 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir pillow==3.4.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir tensorflow==1.2.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir python-snappy==0.5.1 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir xgboost==0.6a2 && \
# Install IPython related packages with no-deps, to ensure that we don't
# Overwrite the python 2 version of jupyter with the python 3 version.
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ipywidgets==6.0.0 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir notebook==4.2.3 && \
    pip3 install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir ipykernel==4.5.2 && \
    find /usr/local/lib/python3.4 -type d -name tests | xargs rm -rf && \

# Install python2 version of notebook after the python3 version, so that we
# default to using python 2.
# Install notebook after ipywidgets, and keep it pinned to 4.2.3, higher versions may
# not work well with datalab. For example, kernel gateway doesn't work with 4.3.0 notebook
# (https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1083)
    pip install -U --force-reinstall --no-deps --no-cache-dir notebook==4.2.3 && \
    pip install -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir notebook==4.2.3 && \

# Install the Python 2 and Python 3 kernels
    python -m ipykernel install && \
    python3 -m ipykernel install && \


# Setup Node.js using LTS 6.10
    mkdir -p /tools/node && \
    wget -nv https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -O node.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf node.tar.gz -C /tools/node --strip-components=1 && \
    rm node.tar.gz && \

# Setup Google Cloud SDK
# Also apply workaround for gsutil failure brought by this version of Google Cloud.
# (https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=538) in final step.
    wget -nv https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.zip && \
    unzip -qq google-cloud-sdk.zip -d tools && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk.zip && \
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false \
        --path-update=false --bash-completion=false \
        --disable-installation-options && \
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud -q components update \
        gcloud core bq gsutil compute preview alpha beta && \
    # disable the gcloud update message
    tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set component_manager/disable_update_check true && \
    touch /tools/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/google.py && \

# Set our locale to en_US.UTF-8.
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && \

# Add some unchanging bits - specifically node modules (that need to be kept in sync
# with packages.json manually, but help save build time, by preincluding them in an
# earlier layer).
    /tools/node/bin/npm install \
        ws@1.1.4 \
        http-proxy@1.13.2 \
        mkdirp@0.5.1 \
        node-uuid@1.4.7 \
        bunyan@1.7.1 \
        tcp-port-used@0.1.2 \
        node-cache@3.2.0 && \
    cd / && \
    /tools/node/bin/npm install -g forever && \

# Clean up
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/* && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/locale/* && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/i18n/locales/* && \
    cd /

ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

ADD config/ipython.py /etc/ipython/ipython_config.py
ADD config/nbconvert.py /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

# Directory "py" may be empty and in that case it will git clone pydatalab from repo
ADD pydatalab /datalab/lib/pydatalab
ADD nbconvert /datalab/nbconvert

# Do IPython configuration and install build artifacts
# Then link stuff needed for nbconvert to a location where Jinja will find it.
# I'd prefer to just use absolute path in Jinja imports but those don't work.
RUN ipython profile create default && \
    jupyter notebook --generate-config

RUN if [ -d /datalab/lib/pydatalab/.git ]; then \
        echo "use local lib"; \
      else \
        git clone https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab.git /datalab/lib/pydatalab; \
      fi
RUN cd /datalab/lib/pydatalab && \
    /tools/node/bin/npm install -g typescript && \
    tsc --module amd --noImplicitAny --outdir datalab/notebook/static datalab/notebook/static/*.ts && \
    tsc --module amd --noImplicitAny --outdir google/datalab/notebook/static google/datalab/notebook/static/*.ts && \
    /tools/node/bin/npm uninstall -g typescript
RUN cd /datalab/lib/pydatalab && \
    pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir . && \
    pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed /datalab/lib/pydatalab/solutionbox/image_classification/. && \
    pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed /datalab/lib/pydatalab/solutionbox/structured_data/. && \
    pip3 install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-cache-dir . && \
    pip3 install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed /datalab/lib/pydatalab/solutionbox/image_classification/. && \
    pip3 install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed /datalab/lib/pydatalab/solutionbox/structured_data/. && \
    jupyter nbextension install --py datalab.notebook && \
    jupyter nbextension install --py google.datalab.notebook && \
    jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension && \
    rm datalab/notebook/static/*.js google/datalab/notebook/static/*.js && \
    mkdir -p /datalab/nbconvert && \
    cp -R /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/gcpdatalab/* /datalab/nbconvert && \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.css /datalab/nbconvert/custom.css && \
    cd /

## Use Debian unstable via pinning -- new style via APT::Default-Release
RUN echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian sid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-unstable.list \
    && echo 'APT::Default-Release "testing";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/default

ENV R_BASE_VERSION 3.4.3

## Now install R and littler, and create a link for littler in /usr/local/bin
## Also set a default CRAN repo, and make sure littler knows about it too
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -t unstable -y --no-install-recommends \
        libssh2-1-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        littler \
                r-cran-littler \
        r-base=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        r-base-dev=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        r-recommended=${R_BASE_VERSION}* \
        && echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"), download.file.method = "libcurl")' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site \
        && echo 'source("/etc/R/Rprofile.site")' >> /etc/littler.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/install.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install2.r /usr/local/bin/install2.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/installGithub.r /usr/local/bin/installGithub.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/testInstalled.r /usr/local/bin/testInstalled.r \
    && install.r docopt \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN     R -e 'install.packages("devtools")' && \
    R -e 'devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")' && \
    # or 'devtools::install_local("IRkernel-master.tar.gz")' && \
    R -e 'IRkernel::installspec()' && \
# to register the kernel in the current R installation 
    R -e 'install.packages("googleAuthR"); library(googleAuthR); gar_gce_auth()' && \
    R -e 'install.packages("bigQueryR"); install.packages("googleCloudStorageR")' && \
    R -e 'install.packages("feather")' && \
    R -e 'install.packages("tensorflow")' && \
    R -e 'devtools::install_github("apache/spark@v2.2.0", subdir="R/pkg")'
```

Comment: why has the PR gone stale?